# How can use paste_data_images true without removing the white spaces TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I want to use paste_data_images as true and I successfully do that but the issue that when I copy codes it's removed the white spaces.

paste_data_images == true:
[image]

paste_data_images == false:
[image]

```
.colorpicker {
    width: 356px;
    height: 176px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://www.aaronolin.com/codepen/colorpicker/images/colorpicker_background.png);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999999999;
    top:20px;
}
.colorpicker_color {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    left: 14px;
    top: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

How can use paste_data_images true without removing the white spaces TinyMCE?

Comment: Post real code, not images.

Comment: @PedroLobito Done